# Is there an API call that will show me the location of a hosts file on given system?

Tags: windows, winapi, hosts

I mean file that is actually in use of user running the program.

Or must I manually check possible paths as in this table: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29#Location_in_the_file_system

Comment: Looking at the linked table: there is only place to look at if you are targeting Windows versions that are not older than 20 years. So what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Windows API call you can use to find the directory, where the *hosts* file resides. As explained in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29#Location_in_the_file_system) in your question, however, the file is in a fixed sub directory of the *%SystemRoot%* directory.

You can retrieve the fully qualified pathname to the *%SystemRoot%* (which is the same as [*%WinDir%* for NT-based systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows)) calling [SHGetKnownFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188.aspx) passing a [FOLDERID_Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457.aspx) *KNOWNFOLDERID*.

The following code returns the fully qualified pathname to the hosts file on all supported versions of Windows:

```
#include <comdef.h>
#include <ShlObj.h>
#include <string>

std::wstring GetHostsPathName() {
    wchar_t* systemRoot;
    _com_util::CheckError( ::SHGetKnownFolderPath( FOLDERID_Windows,
                                                   0x0,
                                                   nullptr,
                                                   &systemRoot ) );
    std::wstring hostsPathName( systemRoot );
    ::CoTaskMemFree( systemRoot );
    systemRoot = nullptr;
    hostsPathName.append( L"\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts" );
    return hostsPathName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an API call that will show me the location of a hosts file on given system?

No, there is no such API call. You would need to know where the file is if you want to access it.